# Google Play Console Alpha Test Email List

Tags: android, google-play-console, release-management

I have an app already having some testers in the alpha test on Google Play Console. I have added some emails to the the tester email list but for those new email when it clicks the tester link it showed the message below:
[image]

Would like to ask if there is any additional steps I need to do or how long does it take for the updated email list to be effective?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Google Account email address you have logged in as matches the one that that is on the testing list.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6316959?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en